# Django: Selecting queryset fields based on a condition

Tags: python, sql, django, django-queryset

Folks,

Here's the schema of the table T (Let's say Model name is also T with fields A, B and C):

```
 A    B   C
---  --- ---
 1    a   b
 2    b   NULL
 3    c   c
```

Now, I want to select values (A, C or B). I can select A and C as follows:

```
 T.objects.all().values_list('A','C')
```

But it will give me A and C values only. All I want is if C is NULL, then I should get B. I don't know whether I can achieve this directly using any condition or join (Sorry, I'm not a SQL guy) but I can definitely achieve this using follows:

```
 [(x,z or y) for (x,y,z) in T.objects.all().values_list('A','B','C')]
```

So, there are two open questions:

1. Is there any **better way** of doing it? (Preferably using Queryset/Django ORM functions)
2. In case of tens of thousands of records, what is the **memory efficient / optimized way** of doing this? Is there any way other than limiting the queryset into smaller chunks (let's say 1000 records at once) using the loop (assuming ordered primary key) as follows:

   > ```
   > max_pkey = T.objects.all().order_by('-pk')[0]
   > current = 0
   > chunk = 1000
   > while current <= max_pkey:
   >     objs = T.objects.filter(pk__gt=current)[:chunk]
   >     Process the objects
   > ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer the first question.

**1. Is there any better way of doing it? (Preferably using Queryset/Django ORM functions)**

Django provides [Conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) that lets you do this.

From Django docs,

> Conditional expressions let you use if … elif … else logic within filters, annotations, aggregations, and updates. A conditional expression evaluates a series of conditions for each row of a table and returns the matching result expression.

For the schema you provided, you can use this:

```
T.objects.annotate(colA = F('A'), 
                   colB_C = Case(When(C__isnull=True, then=F('B')),
                                 default=F('C')))
```

For every row, this selects the value in column B if the value in column C is null. Otherwise, value in column C is selected.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your second question for very large data sets you may want to look at the iterator:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator

As this won't try and load the entire data set at time of evaluation, but obviously there are trade offs.